How to write a modern c++ program (with RAII) using WINAPI, of 4 threads with ids 1-4, looping 1000 times and printing theirs ids and iteration number
The task is to write a c++ program that creates 4 threads, that each of them loops a 1000 times, and each time prints his thread-id and the loop count. All 4 threads work separately.

This program must use the WINAPI functions.
The program must use the RAII concept.

As a starter, I have written a simple answer without RAII that seems to work properly:
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

constexpr int THREAD_COUNT = 4;
constexpr int LOOP_COUNT = 1000;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam) {
    int threadId = reinterpret_cast<INT_PTR>(lpParam);
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_COUNT; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread " << threadId << ", var = " << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<HANDLE> threadHandles;

    for (int i = 1; i <= THREAD_COUNT; ++i) {
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(i), 0, NULL);
        if (hThread == NULL) {
            std::cerr << "Error creating thread " << i << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        threadHandles.push_back(hThread);
    }

    DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(THREAD_COUNT, threadHandles.data(), TRUE, INFINITE);
    if (dwWaitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        std::cerr << "WaitForMultipleObjects failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for (HANDLE hThread : threadHandles) {
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    return 0;
}

Yet, when trying to add RAII, something doesn't quite work (the threads randomly stop at the middle of the iteration):
ThreadHandle.h
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>

class ThreadHandle
{
public:
    ThreadHandle() = default;
    ThreadHandle(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE function, LPVOID lpParameter);
    ~ThreadHandle();
    operator HANDLE() const { return hThread; }
private:
    HANDLE hThread;
};

ThreadHandle.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ThreadHandle.h"

ThreadHandle::ThreadHandle(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE function, LPVOID lpParameter) : hThread(nullptr)
{
    hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        function,
        lpParameter,
        0,
        NULL
    );
    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Create thread failed");
    }
}

ThreadHandle::~ThreadHandle()
{
    if (hThread == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    CloseHandle(hThread);
}

main.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "ThreadHandle.h"

#define THREAD_COUNT 4
#define LOOP_COUNT 1000

DWORD WINAPI LoopThousand(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    int threadId = reinterpret_cast<int>(lpParam);
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP_COUNT; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Thread " << threadId << ", var = " << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<HANDLE> handles;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= THREAD_COUNT; i++)
        {
            ThreadHandle hThread(LoopThousand, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(i));
            handles.push_back(hThread);
        }
        if (WaitForMultipleObjects(
            THREAD_COUNT,
            handles.data(),
            TRUE,
            INFINITE
        ) == WAIT_FAILED)
            throw std::runtime_error("Wait for multiple objects failed");
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Would like some help on the matter (and feel free to give corrections on the given code).

This is a Rule of three / five violation. The push_back call creates a copy of hThread, and then the original is destroyed. This results in two copies of ThreadHandle managing the same thread, one of which immediately closes the thread handle. Construct in-place with emplace_back, or better still implement a move constructor and delete copy constructor/assignment.

threads are non-copyable. Your ThreadHandle should be non-copyable too. Or make it ref counting (you can make ThreadHandle have shared pointer to a ThreadHandleImpl as member to get the ref counting for free)

@paddy
Ok, so I declared the copy constructor and copy assignment operator as private without giving a definition. I understand that the problem is me constructing a ThreadHandle object, and then copying it with the push_back. Yet, if I try to have a one-liner of creating a ThreadHandle object and pushing it to the array with emplace_back, I can only do so to a ThreadHandle array. And then - I have a problem when calling WaitForMultipleObjects and need to supply a pointer to a HANDLE array (yet I have a pointer to a ThreadHandle array).
Not really sure yet how to solve it.

@Torch Alternatively, you can delete the constructors. Keep in mind there is also a move constructor that has specific rules.
